# How do I tell if apache is running as prefork or worker?

Tags: apache-2.2

How do I tell if apache is running (or configured to run) as prefork or worker?

Comment: or more technically 'compiled to run as'

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The MPM is configured at compile time. One way to figure it out afterwards is to list compiled in modules. That list will include the chosen MPM. The listing can be accomplished running the apache binary, with the -l flag.

```
andreas@halleck:~$ apache2 -l
Compiled in modules:
 core.c
 mod_log_config.c
 mod_logio.c
 worker.c
 http_core.c
 mod_so.c
andreas@halleck:~$
```

Here we find the module worker.c, hence I'm running the worker MPM.

Comment: This answer is wrong. See my answer.

Comment: Hm, on Ubuntu I have neither worker nor prefork listed when I do this...

Comment: On Ubuntu you can use `apache2ctl -M` to list active modules.

Answer (score 69):

In Ubuntu 14.04

```
a2query -M
```

Tells `event`, `prefork`, `worker`

You can change it by adding symbolic links for `mpm_<chosen>` from `mods-available` to `mods-enabled` in `/etc/apache2`.

Only one is allowed in a time.

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer.

Comment: yes, great answer! simple and returns what's needed

Comment: Worked for me the best, thanks
(worked on apache 2.4.... looks like it doesn't work on apache 2.2)

Comment: The `event` MPM is, according to Apache's site, "a variant of the worker MPM with the goal of consuming threads only for connections with active processing".

Comment: command not found

Answer (score 65):

The answers given by Series8217 and Andol are both incorrect.

The question was, how to tell if Apache is ***running*** prefork or worker.  The advice given by the other answers only tells what the ***default*** MPM is (based on compiled-in modules), not if that default or another choice is being used at the present time.

If `httpd -V` shows prefork, that just means prefork is the compiled-in default MPM.  That can be overridden by changing an Apache configuration file setting, as shown in this process:

1. Edit the configuration file (e.g. `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` on CentOS / RedHat)
2. Add or uncomment this line: `HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker`
3. Restart Apache

Which MPM is actually running can be shown using this process:

1. Enable Apache mod_info
2. Query the mod_info url, typically `curl localhost/server-info`
3. The "Server Settings" section will show "MPM Name: Worker"
4. Run `httpd -V` again -- it will still show prefork, not worker

Bottom line:

- `httpd -V` shows the default option, not which option is actually in use

There are answers on many, many web sites saying, use `httpd -V` to tell if Apache is running prefork or worker.  They are all wrong.  Try the above procedure to see for yourself.

Comment: FYI, according to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mpm.html the MPM can be a static module on all platforms, or built as a DSO (on Unix). When it is built as a static module, "The server must be rebuilt in order to change the MPM." Is the apache documentation incorrect about the static module MPM being unchangeable except by rebuilding the server?

Comment: This sounds very much like something distro specific, with a higher level wrapper around?

Comment: On CentOS 6.6 /usr/sbin/httpd, /usr/sbin/httpd.event and /usr/sbin/httpd.worker are all distinct binaries with different MPM configured at compile time (prefork, event and worker respectively). Changing the setting of HTTPD in /etc/sysconfig/httpd just controls which binary is run by the init script.

Comment: I had to run apache2 -V instead of httpd -V on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 7):

On RedHat and derivates, just launch `top` or `ps aux` and look at the httpd process name:

- `httpd` means Apache is running as prefork
- `httpd.worker` means it is running as worker

Comment: I see apache2 processes

Answer (score 6):

One way that I figure it out in Debian like distros, is by running:

```
apachectl -V | grep -i mpm
```

Comment: Concrete and good answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Chris Johnson is correct. Go to **httpd.conf** => add this line:

```
<Location /server-info>
SetHandler server-info
</Location>
```

Restart apache: /etc/init.d/httpd restart.
Then access **localhost/server-info** by your browser and **look at MPM Name section**.

Comment: Of even nicer, put that between <IfModule info_module> </IfModule>

Answer (score 4):

On RHEL/Fedora/etc, run `httpd -V`. You will get some output which includes the following:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)
     ...
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
     ...
```

Here 'Server MPM' is 'Prefork', so my server is running the prefork MPM.

Comment: This answer is wrong. See my answer.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson, interesting discovery... My understanding was that the MPM could not be changed by configuration, only by compilation. It seems the OP thought the same, since he commented on his question with "or more technically 'compiled to run as'". I'll look into reproducing your answer and once I've confirmed it I'll revoke mine.

Comment: I confirmed via the apache documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mpm.html that MPMs can be built as DSO modules and dynamically loaded with the LoadModule directive, on "Unix and similar platforms". So the MPM can indeed be changed at load time under certain circumstances (which might be the most common configuration these days..)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another method that I expect should be reliable in determine which MPM is in use. Add the following to your `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
    Header append X-MPM prefork
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
    Header append X-MPM worker
</IfModule>
```

Then check the headers using `curl -I localhost | grep X-MPM`.

Answer (score 3):

on centos (or rhel) you can run this command:

```
ps -ef | grep httpd
```

if you see `/usr/sbin/httpd.worker` running, then it is using the worker MPM. if you see `/usr/sbin/httpd` running, then it is using prefork

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Chris Johnson is right.

After enabling the info module, as documented in the Apache Documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html), this one liner will give you the MPM you're using:

```
links -dump http://localhost/server-info/?server | grep "MPM Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu you can use `apache2ctl -M` (others have the apachectl variant), which lists the available modules.